# Bus error: 10 don't know why

Tags: c, strcat

This piece of code should concat 2 strings, but I'm getting Bus error: 10. I've researched about it, so I gave t1 more space, but I'm still getting that error. Can you help me out?
Thanks in advance!

```
char *strCat (char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i=0,j=0;

    while (s1[i++]);

    while (s2[j])
    {
        s1[j++] = s2[j++];
    }

    s1[j] = '\0';

    return s1;
}

int main()
{
    char t1[10] = "asd";
    char t2[] = "fgh";
    printf("%s", strCat(t1,t2));
}
```

Comment: `s1[j++] = s2[j++];` *Why*. You're invoking undefined behavior here. Do `j++` on one line, `s1[j] = s2[j]` on another.

Comment: @computerfreaker But isn't it the same thing? Anyway, I made the changes, but as result I got "fgh" and not "asdfgh". Anything else wrong?

Comment: It's actually not the same thing at all. You're doing `j++` twice in the same line, which is [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points). By splitting the code into two lines, you're removing one of the `j++`s and stopping the UB.

Comment: The other thing I'm noticing here: `while (s2[j])`. You loop through s1 with `i`, but never actually copy that endpoint to `j`. Let me run through this in my code editor and I'll post a proper answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with this segment of code.

```
while (s2[j])
{
    s1[j++] = s2[j++];
}
```

Because `j++` is being executed twice in the same line, you're invoking [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points). This will go away if we move the `j++` to its own line:

```
while (s2[j])
  {
    s1[j] = s2[j];
    j++;
  }
```

There are two more issues with your code. First, you use one counter (`i`) to get to the end of `s1`, but don't use it when appending `s2` to `s1`. Let's fix that:

```
while (s2[j])
  {
    s1[i] = s2[j];
    i++;
    j++;
  }
```

We'll need to do the same thing when appending the trailing `\0` to `s1`:

```
s1[j] = '\0';
```

becomes

```
s1[i] = '\0';
```

Second is a minor off-by-one bug with `i`.

```
while (s1[i++]);
```

If you mentally trace through this, `i++` will evaluate once more than you want, putting `i` at 4 when the loop ends. However, at this point, there are only three characters in `s1`: `asd`. a = character 0, s = character 1, d = character 2. We want to start writing `s2` one character past this, so we want to start writing from character **3**. Adjusting your loop to match,

```
while (s1[i++]);
i--;
```

You could also do this for clarity's sake:

```
while (s1[i])
{
  i++;
}
```

Now, putting it all together:

```
#include <iostream>

char *strCat(char s1[], char s2[])
{
  int i = 0, j = 0;

  while (s1[i])
  {
    i++;
  }

  while (s2[j])
  {
    s1[i] = s2[j];
    i++;
    j++;
  }

  s1[i] = '\0';

  return s1;
}

int main()
{
  char t1[10] = "asd";
  char t2[] = "fgh";
  printf("%s", strCat(t1, t2));
}
```

And this works as expected.